# Expanding the floor function. $ \lfloor n/p \rfloor=?$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

$n$ is a positive integer. Than we can write this.

$$\lfloor n/2  \rfloor= \left(n+\frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{2}\right)\frac{1}{2}$$

I wonder can we do that simplifying with other dividers? Like can we do the similar thing to $\lfloor n/3 \rfloor$?

Comment: \lfloor and \rfloor for the floor function delimiters.

Comment: If you allow using $k$-th (complex) roots of unity, then it's possible to express any $k$-periodic function in this way.

Comment: Can you at least show that for at least $\lfloor n/3 \rfloor$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We obtain a formula for $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor$ using the $p$-th root of unity
\begin{align*}
\omega_j=e^{\frac{2j\pi i}{p}}\qquad\qquad 0\leq j \leq p-1
\end{align*}

> The following holds true for $n\geq 0, p\geq 1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor&=\frac{n}{p}-\frac{p-1}{2p}+\frac{1}{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{\omega_j^{n-p+1}}{w_j-1}\qquad\qquad \omega_j=e^{\frac{2j\pi i}{p}}
> \end{align*}
>
> For $p=2,3,4$ we get
>   \begin{align*}
> \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor&=\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\left(1-(-1)^{n}\right)\\
> \left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor
> &=\frac{n}{3}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{18}(3-i\sqrt{3})\left(-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n
> +\frac{1}{18}(3+i\sqrt{3})\left(-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n\\
> \left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor&=\frac{n}{4}-\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{8}\left((-1)^n+\left(1+(-1)^n\right)i^n-\left(1-(-1)^n\right)i^{n+1}\right)
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> Since for  $n\geq    0$
>   \begin{align*}
> S(n,p)=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}w_j^n=
> \begin{cases}
> 1&\qquad p|n\\
> 0&\qquad otherwise
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>   we  get for $0\leq j\leq p-1$
>   \begin{align*}
> S(n-j,p)=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}w_j^{n-j}=
> \begin{cases}
> 1&\qquad n\equiv j(\bmod\,p)\\
> 0&\qquad otherwise
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

*Example:* $p=4$

\begin{align*}
\left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor&=\frac{n}{4}-
\begin{cases}
0&\qquad n\equiv 0(\bmod\,4)\\
\frac{1}{4}&\qquad n\equiv 1(\bmod\,4)\\
\frac{2}{4}&\qquad n\equiv 2(\bmod\,4)\\
\frac{3}{4}&\qquad n\equiv 3(\bmod\,4)\\
\end{cases}\\
&=\frac{n}{4}-\frac{1}{4}S(n-1,4)-\frac{2}{4}S(n-2,4)-\frac{3}{4}S(n-3,4)
\end{align*}

> We obtain for general $p$
>   \begin{align*}
> \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor&=\frac{n}{p}-\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{k}{p}S(n-j,p)\\
> &=\frac{n}{p}-\frac{1}{p^2}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\omega_j^{n-k}\\
> &=\frac{n}{p}-\frac{1}{p^2}\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\omega_j^n\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k\omega_j^{-k}\\
> &=\frac{n}{p}-\frac{p-1}{2p}-\frac{1}{p^2}\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\omega_j^n\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k\omega_j^{-k}\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> In (1) we extract the summand with $j=0$ ($\omega_0=1$).

Since 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}kx^k&=x\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}kx^{k-1}=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}x^k
=x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-x^p}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{(p-1)x^{p+1}-px^p+x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align*}

> we obtain with $x=\frac{1}{\omega}$ from (1)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor&=\frac{n}{p}-\frac{p-1}{2p}
> -\frac{1}{p^2}\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{w_j^p-p\omega_j+p-1}{(w_j-1)^2}\omega_j^{n-p+1}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{n}{p}-\frac{p-1}{2p}+\frac{1}{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{\omega_j^{n-p+1}}{w_j-1}
> \end{align*}

Let's look at the formula for small $p=2,3,4$

> *Example: $p=2$*
>
> With $\{\omega_0,\omega_1\}=\{1,-1\}$ we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor&=\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{1}\frac{w_j^{n-1}}{w_j-1}\\
> &=\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}(-1)^{n-1}\\
> &=\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\left(1-(-1)^{n}\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> *Example: $p=3$*
>
> With $\{\omega_0,\omega_1,\omega_2\}=\{1,-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\}$ we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor&=\frac{n}{3}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\sum_{j=1}^{2}\frac{w_j^{n-2}}{w_j-1}\\
> &=\frac{n}{3}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{18}(3-i\sqrt{3})\left(-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n
> +\frac{1}{18}(3+i\sqrt{3})\left(-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n
> \end{align*}
>
> *Example: $p=4$*
>
> With $\{\omega_0,\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3\}=\{1,i,-1,-i\}$ we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor&=\frac{n}{4}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=1}^{3}\frac{w_j^{n-3}}{w_j-1}\\
> &=\frac{n}{4}-\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{i^{n-3}}{i-1}+\frac{(-1)^{n-3}}{-2}+\frac{(-i)^{n-3}}{-i-1}\right)\\
> &=\frac{n}{4}-\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{8}\left((-1)^n+\left(1+(-1)^n\right)i^n-\left(1-(-1)^n\right)i^{n+1}\right)
> \end{align*}

Comment: that's called the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) of $x(n) = n/p - \lfloor n/p \rfloor$

Comment: @user1952009: Nice comment! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Floor function:

$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor =\frac{n+1}{k}+\frac{i \log \left(-(-1)^{\frac{2 (n+1)}{k}}\right)}{2 \pi }-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Mathematica: https://pastebin.com/5BjwBeen